# Iterating over all rows with the same id and find matching values in a different table

Tags: sql-server

I want to find all PSPIDs from the first table for which every QUESTIONID linked to that PSPID, should be present in the second table. Those PSPIDs with even a single QUESTIONID not present in the second table should be excluded.

[image: Tables]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following. It lists all PSPID's where all questions have been answered.

```
SELECT DISTINCT qq.PSPID
  FROM PSP_QUESTION_MASTER AS qq
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT q.QUESTIONID FROM PSP_QUESTION_MASTER AS q
                    WHERE q.PSPID = qq.PSPID
                   EXCEPT
                   SELECT a.QUESTIONID FROM PSP_ANSWER_MASTER AS a
                    WHERE a.PSPID = qq.PSPID);
```